# jQuery returns undefined for formaction property on button

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core

In asp.net core 2.2 i have a button

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-info mt-3 mb-3" type="button" id="btnAdd" asp-action="Add" asp-controller="Reports" asp-area="Companies" asp-route-companyID="@Model.CompanyID">Add</button>
```

which renders the button as

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-info mt-3 mb-3" type="button" id="btnAdd" formaction="/Companies/1/Reports/Add">Add</button>
```

but in jQuery `$("#btnAdd").prop("formaction")` returns undefined and
`$("#btnAdd").attr("formaction")` returns correct value as `/Companies/1/Reports/Add`

Answer (score 1):

This is because `formaction` is not a standard property of an Element object, hence `prop()` will not work for retrieving the value.

You will need to use `attr()` to instead retrieve the value from the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Button formAction Property](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_pushbutton_formaction.asp) which sets or returns the value of the formaction attribute of a button :

```
document.getElementById("btnAdd").formAction;
```

The [formaction attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_formaction.asp) specifies where to send the form-data when a form is submitted. This attribute overrides the HTML form's action attribute.

**The formaction attribute is only used for buttons with type="submit".** So modify the type of your button :

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-info mt-3 mb-3" id="btnAdd" asp-action="Add" asp-controller="Reports" asp-area="Companies" asp-route-companyID="@Model.CompanyID">Add</button>
```

Comment: i am using ajax to submit the form. if set type to `submit` then form gets submitted twice